# Is there function that converts 0.888 to 0.9

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What's the best way to convert 1.88 this values to 1.9 and 1.84 to 1.8 this.

Comment: ROUND() will do that

Comment: Next time try to re-write your question to be more generic, avoiding unnecessary details, especially in the title, providing only an example in the question body. I imagine this one of the reasons why you got so many downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So try 
=round(A1,1)

Assuming that 1.84 is in A1 it will return 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to ROUND() as already explained you can use:

=ROUNDUP(number;num_digits) to round up
and =ROUNDDOWN(number;num_digits) to round down.

Comment: I voted up because those functions are good, but you would need to choose which one to use for what the OP wants, but they are good when calculating the number of staff ect ie next integer etc.